# Removing some data and replacing them with new ones

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation, filtering

I have a data list where the elements have the form (time, velocity ). I need to remove some malformed elements in places where the data does not change smoothly and then replace those points by interpolating the elements before and after them.

Here is an example of my data:

```
{{27.342, -0.01}, {27.443, -0.03}, {27.546, -0.01}, {27.743, -0.01}, {27.945, -0.01}, 
 {28.145, -0.03}, {28.246, -0.05}, {28.346, -0.06}, {28.547, -0.01}, {28.747, -0.01}, 
 {29.149, -0.01}, {29.249, 0}, {29.45, -0.01}, {29.651, -0.05}, {29.852, -0.05}, 
 {30.053, -0.01}, {30.153, -0.01}}
```

For instance the 7th and 8th elements are malformed since the wind cannot change from -0.3 to -0.05 and -0.6 and then back to -0.01 in 0.1 sec0, so I want to replace them with -0.03 and -0.02.

Comment: {{27.342, -0.01}, {27.443, -0.03}, {27.546, -0.01}, {27.743, -0.01}, {27.945, -0.01}, {28.145, -0.03}, {28.246, -0.05}, {28.346, -0.06}, {28.547, -0.01}, {28.747, -0.01}, {29.149, -0.01}, {29.249, 0}, {29.45, -0.01}, {29.651, -0.05}, {29.852, -0.05}, {30.053, -0.01}, {30.153, -0.01}}

Comment: @farzane How about providing the condition to keep/substitute them?

Comment: "remove the ones which are higher than a specific number"?  Remove the differences?  Or remove some elements?  Or substitute some elements with new ones?  Or add new elements?

Comment: For example the mean of the data before and after that.

Comment: BTW, see `Differences` http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences.html

Comment: I dont get the "the mean of the data before and after that". Being more precise would help.

Comment: I mean the average of two data. Like an interpolation

Comment: Be more precise and explain your problem clearly. If not, I'm afraid that your question might be closed for being unclear.

Comment: It would also greatly help if you could give small input data (like a list of say 5 numbers) and the desired output. And please update your question instead of putting info in the comments. Btw, welcome to Mathematica.SE!

Comment: These data are (time, velocity of wind) I want to remove malformed data so I should design a filter which detect the high slop in velocity then substitute those data with the ones which can be calculated from  the interpolation between the data before and after the malformed data.

Comment: @farzane By malformed data you mean these points not aligned on [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DNJRV.png)?

Comment: Somehow. I want them to change smoothly.

Comment: Here's the thing. If you want a good answer you have to ask a good question. You need to sit back and think about what you need help with, then edit your question and include every important detail that will help us understand clearly. Then we can offer you a solution. Otherwise trying to cut corners in asking a decent question will lead to more back and forth in the comment section that will eventually lead to this question being closed.

Comment: I am not experienced in asking questions in forums. Thanks for your suggestion it seems that I need to gain more experience

Comment: In addition to what @RunnyKine said, here's what actually happened: you ask a question that seems to be answered by `Differences`. Then it turns out what you actually want is a filter to replace data if (roughly) the gradient is higher than some value by some interpolated value. But this is only clear from reading the comments. It would help in getting an answer if you included the info from the comments in the question (maybe with a short version of your data and some rough attempt to do what you want). Basically, imagine you don't know what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = y = RandomReal[1, 100];

p = Position[Differences@x, n_Real /; n > 0.1] + 1 // Flatten;

Table[y[[n]] = (y[[n - 1]] + y[[n + 1]])/2, {n, {p}}];

ListLinePlot[{x, y},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 PlotLegends -> {"original", "substituted"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example, modifying data if first value is > -0.2 :-

```
data = {{27.342, -0.01}, {27.443, -0.03}, {27.546, -0.01},
   {27.743, -0.01}, {27.945, -0.01}, {28.145, -0.03},
   {28.246, -0.05}, {28.346, -0.06}, {28.547, -0.01},
   {28.747, -0.01}, {29.149, -0.01}, {29.249, 0},
   {29.45, -0.01}, {29.651, -0.05}, {29.852, -0.05},
   {30.053, -0.01}, {30.153, -0.01}};

Length[data]
```

> 17

```
datapairs = Partition[data, 2, 1];

takedifferences[onepair_] := Module[{a, b},
  {a, b} = onepair;
  a - b]

diffs = Map[takedifferences, datapairs];

Length[diffs]
```

> 16

```
datatriples = Partition[diffs, 3, 1];

process[onetriple_] := Module[{a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2},
  {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}} = onetriple;
  If[b1 > -0.2, b1 = Mean[{a1, c1}]];
  {b1, b2}]

processed = Join[{First[diffs]}, Map[process, datatriples], {Last[diffs]}];

Length[processed]
```

> 16

```
ListLinePlot[{First /@ diffs, First /@ processed}]
```

[image]

Comment: Added more thorough processing  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the following lines?

```
data = {{27.342, -0.01}, {27.443, -0.03}, {27.546, -0.01}, {27.743, -0.01},
        {27.945, -0.01}, {28.145, -0.03}, {28.246, -0.05}, {28.346, -0.06},
        {28.547, -0.01}, {28.747, -0.01}, {29.149, -0.01}, {29.249,  0}, 
        {29.45, -0.01}, {29.651, -0.05}, {29.852, -0.05}, {30.053, -0.01},
        {30.153, -0.01}}; (* from @ChrisDegnen's answer *)

threshold = .02;
t = UnitStep @ PadLeft[Abs@Differences[data[[All, 2]]] - threshold, Length[data]];
mf = MeanFilter[data[[All, 2]], 1];
newdata = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], (1 - t) data[[All, 2]] + t mf}];
ListLinePlot[{data, newdata},  PlotLegends -> {"data", "newdata"}]
```

[image]